# Why does connection string not work in .NET Core 6

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

I am using the exact same connection string I use in .NET Framework 4.8 to connect to an Azure SQL database, however the same string does not work in .Net Core 6, `System.Data.SqlClient` 4.8.3.

The error says

> Keyword not supported 'authentication'

I am under the assumption that there should be no difference. According to this article it should be supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you please include the actual connection string (x out the password and the end point).

Comment: Yes the keyword authentication is valid for a connection string : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0
As @igor stated we would need the complete connection string, with the confidential informations scrapped out.

Comment: Server=tcp:myserver.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Mydatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myuser@myserver.net;Password=xxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Password';Packet Size=32767